# Set missing column values to a default using AWS Glue Jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-zeppelin, aws-glue

I'm trying to extract a dataset from dynamodb to s3 using Glue. In the process I want to select a handful of columns, then set a default value for any and all rows/columns that have missing values.

My attempt is currently to use the "Map" function, but it doesn't seem to be calling my method.

Here is what I have:

```
def SetDefaults(rec):
    print("checking record")
    for col in rec:
        if not rec[col]:
            rec[col] = "missing"
    return rec

## Read raw(source) data from target DynamoDB 
raw_data_dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("dynamodb", {"dynamodb.input.tableName" : my_dynamodb_table, "dynamodb.throughput.read.percent" : "0.50" } )

## Get the necessary columns  
selected_data_dyf = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = raw_data_dyf, mappings = mappingList)

## get rid of null values
mapped_dyF = Map.apply(frame=selected_data_dyf, f=SetDefaults)

## write it all out as a csv
datasink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=mapped_dyF , connection_type="s3", connection_options={ "path": my_train_data }, format="csv", format_options = {"writeHeader": False , "quoteChar": "-1" })
```

My `ApplyMapping.apply` call is doing the right thing, where `mappingList` is defined by a bunch of:

```
mappingList.append(('gsaid', 'bigint', 'gsaid', 'bigint'))
mappingList.append(('objectid', 'bigint', 'objectid', 'bigint'))
mappingList.append(('objecttype', 'bigint', 'objecttype', 'bigint'))
```

I have no errors, everything runs to completion. My data is all in s3, but there are many empty values still, rather than the "missing" entry I would like.

The "checking record" print statement never prints out. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution:

1. Convert DynamicFrame to Spark DataFrame
2. Use the DataFrame's fillna() method to fill the null values
3. Convert the DataFrame back to DynamicFrame